# Using abstract list functions to iterate over a list of functions in Scheme

Tags: function, dictionary, functional-programming, scheme

How can I write a function `max-list-function` that consumes a list of functions, then produces a function `f` such that for every `x`, `(f x)` produces the maximum value of all the functions `g` in the list of functions?

For example `(max-list-function (lambda (n) (+ n 4)) (lambda (n) (- 15 n))))`
produces a function such that `(f 2)` returns 13 and `(f 10)` returns 14.

This is to be done with abstract list functions (filter, foldr, map, ...) without recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(define (max-list-function flist)
  (lambda (n)
    (foldr max -inf.0
           (map (lambda (f) (f n))
                flist))))
```

Use it like this:

```
(define f (max-list-function 
           (list (lambda (n) (+ n 4)) (lambda (n) (- 15 n)))))

(f 2)
> 13.0

(f 10)
> 14.0
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I thought just posting the complete answer to homework problems was considered harmful.